# High memory use can freeze the OS

Tags: 19.04, ram, memory-usage

On Ubuntu 19, I have used all RAM by opening many applications together (VMWare, Chrome etc..). The PC just froze and I had to reboot it. Does it mean that Ubuntu does not have any protecting mechanism against running out of memory?

My confguration is 8GB RAM + 10GB disk swap partition (used less than 10%). In RAM, I have 4 zswap partitions 1GB each. I can start VMWare guest that uses about 6GB, it means that zswap is properly released. But when I start Chrome in addition to VMWare in host, that should not take more than 0.3GB, the PC freezes. VMWare is configured to swap.

Comment: I configured zswap and I also have large swap area. It looks like the PC froze and did not use swap on disk. Maybe problem that originally sized zswap can not be released in favor of RAM for applications?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have added config info